# React router: wait until fetcher.submit resolves

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I need to to display an alert AFTER the promise from the route action fullfills, but I need to run it from the component which started the action.
Here is the half-working example. Please take a look.
https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-liskov-sloots?file=/src/test.jsx

```
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import { TestFetcher } from "./test";

export default function App() {
  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <TestFetcher />,
      action: async () => {
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
        return null;
      }
    }
  ]);

  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}
```

---

```
import { useFetcher } from "react-router-dom";

export function TestFetcher() {
  const fetcher = useFetcher();

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={click}>{fetcher.state}</button>
    </>
  );

  function click() {
    fetcher.submit({ test: "test" }, { method: "post", action: "/" });
    // need to run alert from here
  }
}
```

Comment: `fetcher.data` or the [`useActionData`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-action-data) hook may be useful here. You will probably need to use a `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the returned action data to trigger the side-effect of displaying an alert.

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks, it works, but it also runs when the page loads for the first time. Can I somehow prevent it from running on the page load?

Comment: The action runs when the page loads, or the `useEffect` hook? You'll likely want to conditionally trigger the alert, i.e. something like `useEffect(() => { if (data) { alert(); } }, [data]);`. This OFC assumes that the data is falsey and doesn't exist until the form is submitted and the action called and returns the data value back to the calling component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `action` is a callback that is attached to the route, triggered when a form action is invoked, like submitting a form. The code will very likely need to wait for the action to complete and check the returned data that will be placed on [`fetcher.data`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-fetcher#fetcherdata). You can use the `useEffect` with a dependency on the form data to conditionally trigger the alert as an intentional side-effect.

Example:

```
export default function App() {
  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <TestFetcher />,
      action: async () => {
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
        return /* return something to the calling component */;
      }
    }
  ]);

  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}
```

```
import { useFetcher } from "react-router-dom";

export function TestFetcher() {
  const fetcher = useFetcher();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (fetcher.data) {
      // run alert from here
    }
  }, [fetcher.data]);

  function click() {
    fetcher.submit({ test: "test" }, { method: "post", action: "/" });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={click}>{fetcher.state}</button>
    </>
  );
}
```